# Removing words inside brackets with regex

Tags: regex, parsing

I want to remove words inside bracket, 
I'm currently using this

```
【.*】
```

> 【remove this】preserve this 【remove this】

but it removes everything for this because there is another bracket

How can I solve this? it also happens on comma

```
◆.*、
```

> ◆ remove this、preserve this、

that regex removes everything because I have 2 commas

Comment: where did you get those strange characters ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use non-greedy matching with `?`, and also escape the brackets, which are special characters:

```
\[.*?\]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try two solutions:

- Lazy Operators (this might not work on your RegEx parser)

  ```
  \[.*?\]

  .*?,
  ```
- Or replace . by a negation list to match any element but the end delimiter:

  ```
  \[[^]]*\]

  [^,]*,
  ```

Answer (score 0):

use a specified character group

```
\[[^\]]+\]
```